# what kind of controller could i use?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, fpga, hardware, plc

I'm newbie about electronics hardware. My question is;
I listed electronic materials at my project. I have 41 digital output and 20 analog input. What kind of controller could i use for my project? microcontroller or fpga based system or plc?

Comment: This is like saying "I need a vehicle to get to 61 different places. What should I get, a car, truck, motorcycle, what model?" It's completely unanswerable without more details.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a newbie, forget about the FPGA.

The answer to your question is you need to make a clear and detailed list of the features you need, then decide how critical it is that these features are implemented in the main microcontroller or in some other helper chips. Then decide on other criteria like size of RAM and Flash, cpu power if you have some crunching to do, availability of dev board, ease of soldering, etc. Then you can go shopping.

For example, you mention digital outputs. So you should think about required voltage levels, maybe isolation, does that need to be relay, open collector, optocoupler, or 5V or 3V3 logic level, max output current, protection, etc. Then what speed do these IO need. Can you multiplex them to reduce the number of IOs? Can you use shift registers or I2C expanders to use a lower pin count micro? How fast do these IO need to be? Do they need a certain protocol? (40 UARTs is more complicated than 40 GPIO), etc.

Then you mention 20 analog inputs, so you should first check how fast you need the ADC to be. If it can be slow (a few kHz or tens of kHz sampling rate) then a multiplexed ADC will be a lot simpler. Also consider number of bits. Consider analog input voltage. Will you need a voltage divider if the analog voltage is high, or an amplifier if it is low? Should you use a multiplexer before the amplifier to avoid having one amplifier per channel? Or an ADC with a programmable gain amplifier and multiplexed inputs, etc.

Also consider logistics: if you have lots of IOs with sensors in various places, some of them far away, it could be simpler to make several boards.

If you don't want to design hardware, then get a PLC. But you still need to know what you need it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Firstly, I am newly graduated electrical and electronics engineer. I have theoretical knowledge but i dont have practice about that. I take lesson for FPGA at university. Summing up my project is vending machine for coffee. servo motorx6 for opening system and below, rail system with x2 step motor. AC motorx3 for grinder.  filter paper system, heater element system, cup dispenser system and bag system. Project has a lot of parallel processes. I hope I was able to explain my question. 
 and... sorry for my bad english:(

Comment: OK! Then the micro won't drive the steppers directly, it needs helper chips for that, that talk something like SPI or I2C, and handle all high current stuff, current limit, protection, detecting when the motor is stuck, etc, etc. Suggest choosing motors first, get motors datasheet, get max current information, then choose driver chip and power supply. Servos should take PWM, so that gives you a number of PWM timers that your micro needs. Unless your servos talk SPI or I2C. So you should have a good idea of the servos first. AC motor means opto triac or relay.

Comment: Heater maybe means temperature sensor? What type, etc. "Lots of parallel processes" means either big state machine, or RTOS like FreeRTOS or ChibiOS. That usually needs a 32 bit CPU with a bit of RAM and Flash (not 2kB) for less headache, nothing expensive, Cortex-M0 is absolutely fine. I like STM32 because the development kit is really nice, fast compiler, debugger works, fast upload, but these days with shortages, CHECK IF IT IS IN STOCK AND THAT YOU HAVE THE CHIPS!

Comment: If you have a coin slot it might talk RS232, same for credit card terminal, so count your serial ports (leave one for debug!) and since you will be using lots of varied hardware, that gives you a shopping list of features for your micro. Note with modern micros of the ARM style, you have too many features anyway, so you'll have no trouble finding one.

Comment: thanks bobflux, i got it, there are approximately 30 motors. (DC geared motor, step motor and servo motor.) Firstly I must look at that motor's datasheet and get information. (including the motor driver.) I use a relay for AC motor. The heater element system has a NTC, SSR? and 2kw heater element. Im not use coins, just credit cards and mobile payment.  Lots of parallel processes mean, for example, working AC motor when heating water.